# Is weblogic open source?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I know that weblogic is proprietary, but is it open source ?

Or at least even though the Weblogic download is binary (.class or .jar files), is there a way we can get the source code of how oracle has implemented the Java EE specification ?

Comment: You can always use decompiler to see what's inside in a compiled class

Answer (score 7):

No, WebLogic is definitely not open-source, never been and will not be. It's an application server being developed by Oracle (even if it was originally a product of BEA, which was acquisited by Oracle - now it's so long since then that we can say it's really Oracle product).

Oracle WebLogic Server (WLS) is in the center of all middleware (and some other too) products of Oracle (SOA Suite, WebCenter, ...). Therefore it is developed with many enterprise features like enterprise logging framework, enterprise monitoring, clustering, caching, and so on... It supports full Java EE 6 stack.

Glassfish application server, on other hand, is the reference implementation (RI) of Java EE. Everytime new Java EE specification version is released, GlassFish has it implemented. You can check the new specification and if you like it, you can wait for WebLogic - it will have it some time later. GlassFish is open-source by nature to let the people see the implementation of Java EE standards. It has come to Oracle with acquisition of Sun Microsystems and it's still actively developed. Currently it's a full RI of Java EE 7 (you certainly know we have Java EE Full profile and Java EE Web profile - for example, Tomcat is a Web profile implementation).

There is no other big difference between WebLogic and GlassFish, however, if you will want to use some other Oracle (middleware) product, you will need to go with WebLogic. If you do just Java EE development, GlassFish is absolutelly sufficient (and from my experience, leaner to work with).

Comment: >`open-source, never been and will not be.` - Never say never ;) Who would have ever thought in the 90-ties that Sonic would run around on a Nintendo console? That said, there indeed aren't any signs that WebLogic will become open source any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

The [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/) Java EE server is the opensource reference implementation.

If you've got a generic interest in how the standards can be implemented this should help.

Comment: So you mean like what RedHat does ? That is they have Fedora and CentOS for free (and for all their experiments) and they have RHEL as the final stable and commercial product (derived from Fedora and centOS) ?

Comment: Not exactly, WebLogic is a completely separate code-base from GlassFish, you cannnot infer anything about WebLogic from Glassfish. I doubt you'll get access to WebLogic source, that's commercial. If you just want to understand the standard a bit better Glassfish shows how JEE can be implemented.